# What is ambiguous about this derived interface getter?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I am looking to add these interfaces:

```
public interface IIndexGettable<TKey, TValue>
{
    TValue this[TKey key]{ get; }
}

public interface IIndexSettable<TKey, TValue>
{
    TValue this[TKey key]{ set; }
}

public interface IIndexable<TKey, TValue> : IIndexGettable<TKey, TValue>, IIndexSettable<TKey, TValue>
{   
  // new TValue this[TKey key]{ get; set; } // as suggested by SO question 1791359 this will "fix" the issue.
}
```

When I then try to use an `IIndexable`'s getter, I get the following compiler error:

`The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'IIndexGettalbe<TKey, TValue>.this[Tkey]' and 'IIndexSettable<TKey, TValue>.this[TKey]'`

Here is the code I was running:

```
public static class IIndexableExtensions
 {
    public static Nullable<TValue> AsNullableStruct<TKey, TValue>(this IIndexable<TKey, object> reader, TKey keyName) where TValue : struct
    {
        if (reader[keyName] == DBNull.Value) // error is on this line.
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return (TValue)reader[keyName];
        }
    }   
 }
```

Shouldn't it unambiguously inherit the getter from the IIndexGettable and the setter from the IIndexSettable?

By the way, I am not trying to have this sound inflammatory towards the language design.  I am sure there is a good reason behind this, my goal is to understand what the reason is to get a better understanding of the language.

Comment: off topic maybe, but how about using method instead of property?

Comment: @Ksv3n - my goal is to be able to cast things like dictionary<tkey, tvalue> to IIndexGettable etc.  Otherwise that would work thanks.

Comment: Well you can't cast `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` to `IIndexGettable<TKey, TValue>` because it does not implement that interface (it coincidentally has a method with the same signature, which is not the same thing).  So if that's your goal you are barking up the wrong tree.  You'd have to create a _new_ class that inherits (or encapsulates) `Dictionary` _and_ implements the new interface(s).

Comment: @DStanley: I can do so explicitly :-)

Comment: because both takes`TKey` and also compiler does not look into return type to solve ambiguity. even if it would it was still ambiguous because return types are also same. Note that both getter only and setter only compile to method.

Comment: @user420667 No you can't - a `Dictionary` _is not_ an `IIndexGettable`.  It will compile but will fail at runtime.

Comment: @DStanley: touche.  That's extremely frustrating.  I want to be able to take something that quacks like a duck and treat it like a duck.

Comment: @CodeCaster: yes but I was thinking even more generally.  It could be anything that has an index getter.

Comment: @user420667 Though you defined "Set" only in IIndexSettable, it will contain the defualt "Get" implementation as well. Now when I refer "IIndexable".Get , now the compiler cannot resolve which GET to invoke !!! which leads to this ambiguity. In such cases you have to access RIGHT get explicitly. In this case ((IIndexSettable) IIndexable<K,V> instance).Key would work for you.

Comment: @KarthikDV: Thanks.  Your comment should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Tried the below code, and it works fine. What is the scenario of your error? What's not in this code?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo<int, string> foo = new Foo<int, string>();
            foo.dict.Add(1, "a");
            foo.dict.Add(2, "b");
            Console.WriteLine(((IIndexGettable<int, string>)foo)[1]);
            ((IIndexSettable<int, string>)foo)[3] = "c";
            Console.WriteLine(foo[3]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public interface IIndexGettable<TKey, TValue>
    {
        TValue this[TKey key] { get; }
    }

    public interface IIndexSettable<TKey, TValue>
    {
        TValue this[TKey key] { set; }
    }

    public interface IIndexable<TKey, TValue> : IIndexGettable<TKey, TValue>, IIndexSettable<TKey, TValue>
    {

    }

    public class Foo<TKey, TValue> : IIndexable<TKey, TValue>
    {
        public Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        public TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get
            {
                return dict[key];
            }

            set
            {
                dict[key] = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I updated the OP to show how I was using it so I got the error.  It doesn't appear to yield an error until you actually create an IIndexable object and try to access the indexed getter.

Comment: Hm... I tried your code and my code but for the life of me can't see why mine would fail and yours wouldn't.

Comment: i added your extension method to my code, and it shows the compiler error for me too. And not just when you are reading from reader in your `if` clause, but inside `else` clause too.

Comment: If I cast your foo to an IIndexable, then call the getter, that's where the issue arises.

Comment: Sure, right before your Console.WriteLine I made: var ifoo = (IIndexable<int, string>)foo;  Then I had the Console.WriteLine write the ifoo[1] instead of foo[1].

Comment: There are 2 overloads, the compiler couldn't get which one to call. I had to cast it again to specific getter(IIndexGettable) or setter(IIndexSettable) to use appropriate indexer. Updating my answer.

Comment: Hm... thanks that is helpful.  Would upvote more if I could.  So if I have a method that takes an IIndexable then I have to continually cast it to either IIndexGettable or IIndexSettable depending on how I intend to use it.  In this particular case I could have just used an IIndexGettable for the method parameter and avoided the problem altogether, but I'm not sure I like all the subsequent casting that could be necessary for a more complex method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93104/discussion-between-singsuyash-and-user420667).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question *"What is ambiguous about this derived interface getter?"*

**The type where the property (Parameterful property/accessor) is defined.**

It seems the compiler would check the type first where the property is defined & then if its a Getter or a Setter.

Here we have defined a property with same name & signature in 2 interfaces and this is the ambiguity. It **does not give compiler a change to go to the next step, too check if its a getter or a setter**.

Here is a short experiment which I did to observe its behavior on intellisence too -

I made a simpler set up -

```
public interface IIndexGettable
{
    int Index { get; }
}

public interface IIndexSettable
{
    int Index { set; }
}

 public interface IIndexable : IIndexGettable, IIndexSettable
 {

 }
```

And I now use intellisence to implement the interface `IIndexable`

And here is the issue

```
public class ConcreteIndexable : IIndexable
 {
     public int Index
     {
         get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
     }

     int IIndexSettable.Index
     {
         set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
     }
 }
```

It implements `int IIndexSettable.Index` as an **Explicit interface implementation**  just as it would have done it incase both the interfaces have same function.

Now this auto generated code would have made perfect sense if there were 2 functions in both the interfaces with same name & signature. But as we see, it also handled a property with just `get`and a property with just `set` like they were exactly same, and created an explicit interface implementation. And thats the point I wanted to convey. If you look at the auto genrated code, it does not fit together - an explicit interface implementation, with `set`.

Comment: Thanks for providing a simpler example.  Interesting to note that you can't chagne the setter to public in your `ConcreteIndexable`.

Comment: @user420667 you mean adding  `public` accessibility to `int IIndexSettable.Index` ?

Its not possible to mark it as public or private, because its an explicit interface implementation. When generating the metadata, c# compiler marks it as private. There by preventing any code using the instance of class from simply calling it. The only way to call the interface property is through a variable of interface type.

Comment: @user420667  -  Now this would have made perfect sense if there were 2 functions in both the interfaces with same name & signature. But as we see, it also handled a property with just `get`and a property with just `set` like they were exactly same, and created an explicit interface implementation. And thats the point I wanted to convey. If you look at the auto genrated code, it does not fit together - an explicit interface implementation, with `set`. (I'll add it to my answer too.)

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted in your question, adding the `new` keyword will fix the issue. But a better approach altogether would be to simply have:

```
public interface IReadOnlyIndexable<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<TKey, TValue>
{
    TValue this[TKey key]{ get; }
    int Count { get; }
}

public interface IIndexable<TKey, TValue> : IReadOnlyIndexable<TKey, TValue>
{
    new TValue this[TKey key]{ get; set; }
}
```

One thing is that you will rarely (if ever) want to have a property setter without a getter (I have never used it, never seen it inside BCL, or any well known library). Having a setter-only property would *most likely* mean you are doing something wrong.

And this allows you to do what OOP is supposed to let you do: pass an instance of `IIndexable<T, V>` to methods which accept `IReadOnlyIndexable<TKey, TValue>`, and be sure they won't be able to mutate it.

.NET BCL, starting from .NET 4.5, has a different approach; it defines `IList<T>` / `IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IDictionary<T, V>` / `IReadOnlyDictionary<T, V>`, but mutable interfaces don't inherit from read-only ones. Instead, BCL classes implement both interfaces:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T> ...

public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>,
      IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ...
```

I like the first (inherited) approach better, because it allows a method referencing an instance through its mutable interface to pass the instance to a method needing an immutable instance (which you cannot do with BCL classes):

```
public void ReadStuff(IReadOnlyIndexable<T, K> instance) 
{
    // read from instance
}

public void ReadOrWrite(IIndexable<T, K> instance)
{
    // write to instance
    ReadStuff(instance); // and you can simply pass it as IReadOnlyIndexable
}
```

Btw, I have done something like this a couple of years ago in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233738/IIndexable-a-true-read-only-list-interface), although it's an interface for lists/collections only. But the idea behind the article was probably similar to yours: I wanted to be able to wrap collections in a lightweight readonly wrapper which I could pass around without worrying if some part of my code would accidentally mutate it. And I could add cool LINQ-like extension methods which would allow me to wrap segments of my collections and pass them around as immutable.